# UserForm Issue: ComboBox won't fill with items

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

[code screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qTznT.png)

I've tried several different methods and nothing seems to be working.

Comment: Screenshots of code aren't permitted here; please [edit] your question with the code as text.

Comment: That's a valid way to do it, so I can't see a reason for it not to work. When you say "not working" do you mean that the userform is working, but when you click the arrow, the list is empty after initialization? Also, do you really need to have the rest of the stuff? Isn't initialization always loading it with the default values?

Comment: Are you sure it's `UserForm1_Initialize()` and not `UserForm_Initialize()`?

Comment: When I say "not working", the combobox doesn't fill with the values I have added.

Comment: Yeah, I double checked, it is UserForm1

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode Please create a [reprex].

Answer (score 1):

One way to make sure you are targeting the right object, is by selecting it in the dropdown list.

[image]

Then the `Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()` sub will be created automatically, and is sure to point in the right direction.

The thing about specifically the `UserForm` object, compared to the others, is that it will always be called **UserForm** no matter what the name is, because there will always only be one userform in a userform.